# Toggle anchor will not pull all the way

Tags: drywall, anchor, drywall-anchor

I am installing two toggle anchors in drywall to hold a heavy mirror. The first one went normally, but this second one will not cinch all the way. No human strength can push the plastic disk farther up the tongue. Do I take it out and try another one? Is there something wrong with my wall? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: "*No human strength can push the plastic disk farther up the tongue*" Sounds like a job for the super human strength of "Toggle Man".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the hole I drilled was close to a stud which wasn't letting the anchor lay flat against the wall. I sawed off the plastic front bit of the anchor, let the metal anchor fall into the wall, and put up another one but with the wings in a different orientation.